# Using R to analyze a group of checkboxes in a PDF form

Tags: r, pdf, checkbox

We have created PDF Form rubrics that we use to assess out students' work. For some criteria we use checkboxes that are **almost** like radio buttons, except that some assessors will check off two boxes to indicate partial matches. We've captured the feedback for the class using an Acrobat Response file, and have exported it to CSV for further processing.

What we'd like to do is convert the contents of (e.g.) 4 related checkboxes into a single response value.  For example we have checkboxes named `ClarityU`, `ClarityS`, `ClarityG`, and `ClarityO` which handle the `Clarity` criterion at the `Unacceptable`, `Satisfactory`, `Good`, and `Outstanding` levels. We'd like to convert the `No, Yes, No, No` that we have in the CSV file under the appropriate columns into a single `Satisfactory` under a new `Clarity` column.

I have a suspicion that the `order` function might be helpful, but can't see an elegant, R-like way of accomplishing this task. The problem of having multiple checks for the same criterion is (to me, for the moment) secondary to just getting things mostly correct... but I'll have to figure out when multiple responses were checked at some point!

Thank for any suggested solutions!

Answer (score 2):

You can use nested `ifelse()` statements to recode dummies, though there might be an even more R-tastic way:

```
    resp <- cbind(c(0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0),
    c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1),
    c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0),
    c(0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0))
    colnames(resp) <- c("ClarityU", "ClarityS", "ClarityG", "ClarityO")

    Clarity <- ifelse(resp[,"ClarityU"]==1,"Unacceptable",
        ifelse(resp[,"ClarityS"]==1,"Satisfactory",
        ifelse(resp[,"ClarityG"]==1,"Good","Outstanding")))
    resp <- cbind(resp,Clarity)
     ClarityU ClarityS ClarityG ClarityO Clarity       
     [1,] "0"      "1"      "0"      "0"      "Satisfactory"
     [2,] "0"      "0"      "1"      "0"      "Good"        
     [3,] "0"      "0"      "0"      "1"      "Outstanding" 
     [4,] "1"      "0"      "0"      "0"      "Unacceptable"
     [5,] "1"      "0"      "0"      "0"      "Unacceptable"
     [6,] "0"      "0"      "0"      "1"      "Outstanding" 
     [7,] "1"      "0"      "0"      "0"      "Unacceptable"
     [8,] "0"      "1"      "0"      "0"      "Satisfactory"
     [9,] "0"      "0"      "0"      "1"      "Outstanding" 
    [10,] "0"      "0"      "1"      "0"      "Good"        
    [11,] "0"      "1"      "0"      "0"      "Satisfactory"
```

Comment: you probably want `resp <- data.frame(resp,Clarity)` if you don't want to coerce everything to character type ...

Comment: yeah true, I figured Jason had 'Yes' 'No' anyway. Nifty trick that, wasn't familar with `sweep()` before

Answer (score 1):

Following up on the previous example: in the absence of partial matches,

```
factor(resp %*% (1:4),
       labels=c("Unsatisfactory","Satisfactory","Good","Outstanding"))
```

As the beginning of a solution to double-checks, you could start from

```
rowSums(sweep(resp,MARGIN=2,STATS=1:4,FUN="*"))/rowSums(resp>0)
```

which will give you a numeric score from 1 to 4, averaging multiple scores -- you'd then have to decide how to label non-integer values ...